# How to allocate unallocated hard drive space for large drives

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I got a new computer at work and I have been using it for a while now. I recently went into disk management, and noticed that the person who set up the machine allocated a 3TB HDD in a format that only allows 2TB max partition size - and left the remaining ~TB unallocated. Right clicking the unallocated portion gives me no options to use it, nor does trying to extend the part that is allocated:

[image: trying to extend the allocated portion]

[image: trying to allocate the unallocated portion]

I am hoping there is a simpler solution than to remove all the data from this HDD, reformat it in a sane way, and then put the data back. Any suggestions?

The machine runs Win7 Enterprise

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYhIl.png):

Comment: The solution to your problem is simply.  You format your HDD and use GPT instead of MBR.  You can also convert MBR to GPT if you want.  This is not a simply task and not for the inexperienced.  There exist third-party tools that help you in this conversion process though.

Comment: Formatting the drive involves moving all the data off it first, no?

Comment: If you want the data.

Comment: perhaps there is a reason it was set up that way.  you should check with your IT dept before you do anything.  Remember, its not *your* computer, its the business' computer.

Comment: No, I'm free to modify the machine as I please. It's an academic lab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***If you're not booting from the disk,*** you can convert it from MBR to GPT form without data loss using my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) utility. I believe some other third-party Windows tools can do it, too, but I'm not familiar with which ones can do it, aside from GPT fdisk. The conversion is described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html) After you convert the disk, you can either create new partition(s) in the currently-unallocated space or expand your current partition into the free space.

Note that this type of conversion is not 100% risk-free -- no partitioning operation ever is. The risk is less than you might think, though; partition tables are actually very simple data structures compared to filesystems, so converting from one format to another doesn't involve complex or time-consuming computations. You can (and should) check GPT fdisk's interpretation of the disk (via the `p` command) to verify that it's what you expect before you save the results.

Note that converting a boot disk from MBR to GPT form (or vice-versa) requires installing a new boot loader on the disk. Based on your screen shot, it looks like you're booting from another disk, so this shouldn't be an issue for you, but I may be misinterpreting something.

Comment: You have it right - I have an SSD boot drive, the drive in question is just a data dump. I have good backups, but I will do an extra one and convert. Thank you.